# Production ready Python implementations besides CPython?

Tags: python, ironpython, jython, cpython, pypy

Except for CPython, which other Python implementations are currently usable for production systems?

The questions

- [What are the pros and cons of the various Python implementations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86134/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-the-various-python-implementations)
- [I have been trying to wrap my head around the PyPy project. So, fast-foward 5-10 years in the future what will PyPy have to offer over CPython, Jython, and IronPython?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619437/i-have-been-trying-to-wrap-my-head-around-the-pypy-project-so-fast-foward-5-10) and
- [Migrating from CPython to Jython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/420792/migrating-from-cpython-to-jython/847629#847629)

already shed some light on the pros/cons on the topic. I am wondering now, if those more exotic implementations are actually used in systems that have to run reliably. (possible examples? open-source?)

**EDIT:** I'm asking for code that needs the Python version >= 2.5

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**CPython**

Used in many, many products and production systems

**Jython**

I am aware of production systems and products (a transactional integration engine) based on Jython.  In the latter case the product has been on the market since the early 2000's.  Jython is a bit stagnant (although it seems to have picked up a bit lately) but it is mature and stable.

**IronPython**

This is the new kid on the block, although it does have some track record in products.  It (particularly version 1.x) can be viewed as stable and ready for production use, and development is officially funded by Microsoft, who appear to have an interest in dynamic languages on top of the CLR.  It is the greenest of the major python implementations, but appears to be reasonably stable.

**Stackless Python**

This is used extensively in [EVE Online](http://eve-online.com), and they seem to view it as production ready.  Bear in mind that Stackless Python has been around for something like 10 years.

Comment: [PyPy](http://pypy.org/) needs to be added to this list. Quora is now running on [PyPy](http://www.quora.com/Alex-Gaynor/Posts/Quora-is-now-running-on-PyPy)

Answer (score 3):

At least one product, [Resolver One](http://www.resolversystems.com/), is said to be production-level and is totally based on [IronPython](http://www.codeplex.com/IronPython/).

> Resolver One is a program that blends a familiar spreadsheet-like interface with the powerful Python programming language, giving you a tool with which to better analyse and present your data.

Answer (score 0):

I know that [Jython](http://www.jython.org/Project/) is pretty mature and has been around for a long time.

Also, I'd take a look at [Stackless python](http://www.stackless.com/)

Comment: Jython, up until recently, only had implemented python 2.2.  They have just released an RC2 for version 2.5, but that hardly qualifies it as mature.  Their installation instructions still only reference 2.2.

Answer (score 0):

You can check http://www.portablepython.com/ which is the portable version of CPython. It is also bundled with very common and useful libraries and even an IDE, all portable.

There was Pyrex, which can be found at http://www.cosc.canterbury.ac.nz/greg.ewing/python/Pyrex/. It is not Python, but very close. The Cython (not CPython) is based on Pyrex and can be found at http://www.cython.org/. They are both useful for creating C extensions for Python. Their languages are so Pythonic.